# strong_parameters in Rails using datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm using `strong_parameters` to create a nested object in a `form`. All attributes works properly,  except `datetime` parameters.

There is something special in nested `datetime` parameters?

looking at the console, the parameters are properly nested, but it comes with a special `Ni`, with `N` from 1 to 6 depending on the especification of day, month, year... but when it creates the object (`INSERT INTO`), the specified parameter `datetime` doesn't appears:

```
Processing by ReleasesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", ... "release"=>{ ... "qm_attributes"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "start_at(1i)"=>"2014", "start_at(2i)"=>"3", "start_at(3i)"=>"31", "start_at(4i)"=>"14", "start_at(5i)"=>"57", "end_at(1i)"=>"2014", "end_at(2i)"=>"3", "end_at(3i)"=>"31", "end_at(4i)"=>"14", "end_at(5i)"=>"57", ... }}, "commit"=>"Create Release"}

SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "qms" ("created_at", "release_id", "tipo_qm_release", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

What a bout if you put part of your code here, to have more clear your question, looks like is something relative with .permit()

Comment: I figured you would ask for it. It's all right, and I found out that the "date_time select" html was hindering me. When passed in text, everything works correctly. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Ok nice, do it, so we can check if we can improve your code with some feedback! ;)